# Google Cloud Platform App Engine Standard environment with 4GB RAM

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Could anyone suggest, is it possible to deploy application that consume RAM more than 2 GB. As per the web link provided by Google Cloud Platform documentation its looks not feasible. Web link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum instance size for [App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes) is B8 which provides 2 GB memory.

Comment: Is there any resolution if app consume more than 2gb ram and customer want to use app-engine standard only.

Comment: As per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes), you can see that you can't use more than 2Gb, other way will be to have a App Engine Flexible environment, you can't do more in this.